# Trying to locate a COVID Dataset

Tags: dataset

I have been looking for a dataset that includes:

- Age
- Hospitalized
- ICU
- Disposition (Recovered,Death)

Has anyone located one ? 
Preferably from a western country as China's data is suspect.
I find it hard to believe CDC is not gathering this data.

Comment: have a look in the open data stack exchange, there are a few https://opendata.stackexchange.com/?tab=month

Answer (score 1):

You can find some data and maybe combine from multiple sources, starting with:

https://www.kaggle.com/kimjihoo/coronavirusdataset (what I could come up that includes patient ages from the first Google results)

And for the global stats: https://github.com/datasets/covid-19/blob/master/data/time-series-19-covid-combined.csv or